# Should a micro-service wrap a message queue exposed to a third party vendor?

Tags: architecture, message-queue, microservices

I have a third party vendor that will need to push messages to us. I am considering having them put these messages onto a messaging queue. Because I do not want the micro-service that will need to take action on the queue to be overwhelmed by traffic.

Is it considered good practice to give the third party access to put messages on the queue or should I wrap like RESTful micro-service in around the queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider wrapping the queue in a service.  Being that it is a third-party, you may not have control if/when you need to change things.  For example, if you need to add security, or you need to introduce throttling.

If it were purely internal, the additional abstraction is probably not worth it, but externally exposed resources probably need more control

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely do as you are suggesting. More important than the technological concerns (scalability, fault tolerance etc), is setting up a beneficial dynamic between yourself and your supplier.

If you exposed a queued endpoint directly, then you effectively hand control of contract to the message producer. As the producer of the message, they are effectively able to inject any message they want onto the queue.

Queued data exchange formats are notoriously difficult to nail down from a contract perspective. As well as payload, you have additional concerns such as addressing, headers, encoding, retry, and grouping semantics. With http, in contrast, the entire contract can be described without ambiguity by using an endpoint definition convention such as [swagger](https://swagger.io).

Importantly, by exposing a synchronous service you retain control over the contract. As well as controlling the contract (and therefore the format of the conversation) you will also be able to implement throttling, strict validation, etc with meaningful and helpful responses, all of which would be much harder in an asynchronous scenario.

This is an important distinction because the balance of power in a producer-consumer relationship is very different to the balance of power in a service-consumer relationship. You will find that this simplifies your dealings with said supplier going forward.